# Converting a 4D double dataset to ultimately get the time series

Tags: matlab, mat

I have a dataset `x` that is 4D double, and has a dimension of [3x16x3x300]. 
The dimensions are: State, regions, mode, and time.

I want to convert it to a time series, which should just be `regions`x`time`.

How would I be able to single out the parts that I need in order to get the time series? I thought about reshaping, but I'm not exactly sure what values I should be working with.

The person that I'm working with said she averaged across dimensions and modes, although I don't quite understand what she meant by also. The `regions`x`time` matrix should be 16x300, because afterward I will calculate the functional connectivity, which should be 16 by 16.

Scripts below:

```
fileName = sprintf('BOLD-G01_branch1.h5');
%% path2data = 'output file'
path2data = 'C:/Users/Aiskya/Desktop/test/1009A/';
x = (squeeze(hdf5read(fullfile(path2data,fileName),'/x')));  
N=size(x,2); 
reshape(squeeze(x))     % --> This is the part that I'm confused of
TSsim = x;
TSsim = TSsim(11:end,:);
```

Comment: Do you want regions*time matrix for  a specific State and mode? Can you provide a sample example matrix of what you have and your expected output matrix for that example?

Comment: The problem here is since State and mode are larger than 1, you get  regions*time < 3x16x3x300. So the size won`t fit with reshape() unless you specify state and mode. You need to clarify it.

Comment: The person that I'm working with said she averaged across dimensions and modes, although I don't quite understand what she meant by also. The regions*time matrix should be 16x300, because afterward I will calculate the functional connectivity, which should be 16 by 16.

Answer (score 0):

To average over the dimensions you want to get rid of, follow the following recipe:

```
x = zeros(3,16,3,300); % fill in the actual data here
y = mean(x,1);    % average over dimension 1, output is 1x16x3x300
y = mean(y,3);    % average over dimension 3, output is 1x16x1x300
y = squeeze(y);   % remove dimensions of size 1, output is 16x300
```

The output `y` contains only the `regions` and `time` axes. Each point `y(i,j)` is an average over states and modes `x(:,i,:,j)`.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to answer you back! Is there a reason why you zero the matrix to begin with? Because 'y' just becomes 16x300 matrix filled with 0 instead of actual values.

Comment: @Aiskya: sorry, I should have been more clear. `x` is whatever your data is. You didn’t provide any, so I used a zeros array as example.

Comment: I see! Sorry for not being more specific on what the data `x` should look like. It still gave me 16 by 300, which is what I needed.